# Solr - Suggester

Tags: php, search, solr, autocomplete

Can anyone give me a good Solr Suggester example, I tried to get a phrase suggest using "Solr Suggest" then used "Spell Checker" but didn't get what I needed. Anything on this would help.

Just need a good example link that explains what is done in detail, or at least something close.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am unable to edit my previous answer(deleted now :/). Here is the code snippet for implementing suggestion feature:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
        <lst name="suggester">
  <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
  <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>      <!-- org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst -->
  <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>  
  <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>     <!-- org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.HighFrequencyDictionaryFactory -->
  <str name="field">name</str>
  <str name="weightField">price</str>
  <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
  <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
 </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler"  startup="lazy">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="df">text</str>
  <str name="suggest">true</str>
  <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
  <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
</lst>
<arr name="last-components">
  <str>suggest</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

**Note**: `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory` allows you to search for *infixes* as well. Suppose your search item is `Squash` and the user types `uash`, `Squash` will be provided as a suggestion.

`FuzzyLookupFactory` will allow you to provide suggestion even when the user does a *spelling mistake*.

Answer (score -1):

The following link should help you to implement a phrase suggest.

http://solr.pl/en/2010/11/15/solr-and-autocomplete-part-2/